# Multiple pop up notifications for one line in log entry ()

Tags: python

I have set up few scripts already that monitor up to ten machines over the network and then they all write specific information in one log file. 
What I need is that with every new entry/row in log file a pop up notification alerts me. The problem is I'm getting too many pop ups when new entry is wrote in log.

```
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open(datoteka,"r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        playsound('//IpAddress/foldername/1.mp3')
        if line:
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, line, "Popup name", 0)

printit()
```

Comment: Could you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "too many pop-ups"? Are you getting too many lines added to the log, or is it that your sound is playing more than once?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Thanks for your time. No, the log is fine, I read from it, the thing is when I get one row in log.txt this part should play sound once and make a pop up notification containing that one row. It is working but for one row in log.txt I get 5-6 popup notifications.